# Defining <number | ''> in typescript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types, use-state

Below is my code.

```
const [enteredAge, setEnteredAge] = useState<number | "">("");
```

Have defined the type for useState as number. Having a type like `<number | undefined>` makes sense that we definig the type to be `number` or `undefined`. But in the above given code I have defined `<number|"">` this way. Does this mean only initial state of the `useState` can be defined `""` this way?

Comment: I would assume it means you can initialise it with either a number or empty string. (I do not know typescript very well btw)

Comment: @evolutionxbox yes that's right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `useState<number | "">("");` your state will be initially set to `""` and then can either be set to a number or "" again but not any other string.

You can also initialise it to a number `useState<number | "">(42);` the same way.

```js
const [state, setState] = useState<number | "">("");
const [stateNum, setStateNum] = useState<number | "">(42);

setState("Foo"); // Error: Argument of type '"Foo"' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<number | "">'.ts(2345)

setState(0); // OK
setState(""); // OK
```

Answer (score 1):

If the use is for holding the value for a controlled numeric input, don't store it in a single state variable — instead, store the user input as a raw string value, and use a separate state value for the parsed number type. By doing so, you will never modify the user input in a way that's unexpected (example: try entering `1e6` into the input in the code example below and see how it's parsed as a numeric value:

[TS Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&useUnknownInCatchVariables=true&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAbwFBzgEwKYDMCGBXAG3hwGc4AlDHAYxgBoU4ARYEsHGagCwdUppgBRAhhAYAdvUYBlDDGkwOGAIK1gEcbzh4SGQViwZaWnRgVKGAXzhYoEEHADkUKrUcBuJEhgBPMBjgAOTwQACMMKAAFHCgSYHEAcwAxPHE1DTgAXjgACniwPBgALjgSGCh4hIBKLIA+OHEQ8KhPbz8A4LEK6gBJcQKYJg4cLMRGKBwAdwA1HAI8DBKyisTPVF0YcinZ+cXmVnZOLgAeWXlFGBV08WPlytratbgANzmFksawiM9LVuoNMrobD4IidZrRWKVFJpGDqcQlMERCFxRLQ66jZZ1IJNCI5ZZVVpYVLo0ydCLAXr9Qq5dixDBJeHYr5RGIo5LE2EZbKYXCEGCIlmQ1EcuFVBEhcmUgZDRRjVD-cSAgDaExmbwwdFKci2at2AF1RqZzJcco5HATGArla9dpqNjsFgbskaLhgcrTdAycqqHRgqhbUKZ9IZaDkcjVMvV7er3az6eJvdt1f7NSqk7atTBfXqA3AXDA8FBxIgfeq7dr0wtNTaFr8kJYvESYXC4IIAB44cAiXJiiiuIQiMSSOVwK3wBCljMbHW+6vq6zO3Rk7p9Abhp5BgxGGBhiP1K0QEQAOgIEASOQnlY1L3n-qe+cLxZyx3y1N8-kyACJPs1P3ANAAwlwOCJBgmQIBgzxYtOV45JBR6KFACRyEeNZ+tYaHgZOtZwAA9LUFoNkAA)

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/react@17.0.2/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17.0.2/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone@7.16.4/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset('tsx', {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets['typescript'], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

/**
 * The following line is here because this Stack Overflow snippet uses the
 * UMD module for React. In your code, you'd use the commented `import` lines
 * below it.
 */
const {useEffect, useState} = React;

// import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
// import {default as React, Dispatch, ReactElement, SetStateAction, useEffect, useState} from 'react';

type NumberParsingFunction = (input: string) => number;

type NumericInputData = {
  rawValue: string;
  setRawValue: Dispatch<SetStateAction<string>>;
  value: number;
};

const defaultNumberParsingFunction: NumberParsingFunction = str => Number(str);

function useNumericInput (parseFn: NumberParsingFunction = defaultNumberParsingFunction): NumericInputData {
  const [rawValue, setRawValue] = useState('');
  const [value, setValue] = useState(parseFn(rawValue));
  useEffect(() => setValue(parseFn(rawValue)), [rawValue, setValue]);
  return {rawValue, setRawValue, value};
}

function Example (): ReactElement {
  const {rawValue, setRawValue, value} = useNumericInput();
  useEffect(() => console.log({rawValue, value}));
  return (<input type="number" onChange={ev => setRawValue(ev.target.value)} value={rawValue} />);
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById('root'));

</script>
```